# How to connect to windows shared folder from aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, net-use

I've a requirement to create a csv file and drop it to windows network share drive which is protected by user name and password.
Currently my python scripts creates the csv file and copies the file to the network share drive.
If I want to automate this using lambda function, is it possible? I know lambda runs outside of VPC so not sure if it can mount the windows file drive.

Is there any other way of asking lambda connect to the windows network drive?

Also I am using NET USE in my python script to establish connection to windows network drive. Is this a reliable way of connecting?

Thanks

Comment: The AWS Lambda function can be connected to a VPC, so it can reach the instance. The problem is how to establish the connection from Lambda (which is not a Windows environment) to connect to the Windows drive. You'll need to find a library that can do this and then configure Security Groups to permit the connection. An alternative (and much simpler) approach would be to store the file in an Amazon S3 bucket and have the Windows instance access/fetch it from there. Think of S3 as a 'shared drive' between them both.

Comment: Thank you. Assuming the file is stored in S3 bucket, can it be downloaded directly into the windows shared drive without first downloading it to the local hard drive and then move it to network shared drive? Is that what your'e saying? Ultimately the file has to go inside the network share drive where another app is polling for filtes.

Comment: You could run a command on the Windows instance like `aws s3 sync s3://bucket-name/folder/ H:/local-dir` -- this would **sync** the folders, automatically copying any new/changed files. You could even run the command on a regular basis in a Scheduled Task, or just run it when you want the latest file. The destination can be any drive accessible from the Windows computer so, yes, it could be downloaded straight to the shared drive without going via the C: drive.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the s3 sync command, it works for a normal windows local folder. But doesn't work if its a network folder protected with user/password. Is there a way I can make s3 sync network folder with user/password?

Comment: You'll need to figure out how to supply that information to Windows. A quick web search seemed to suggest to me that Windows can cache the credentials, but I have no experience on the topic.